# Maven - list tests covering one Java class

Tags: java, maven, testing, code-coverage

I have a maven project with tests executed using Surefire and whose code coverage is handled by Jacoco. My test results are then forwarded to SonarQube for analysis for each pull request.

In this context I would like to know the **tests that were executed to cover one class**, in order to list all tests covering the code changed in my pull request.

Any idea how to do this ? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.
You as a developer have to know where the class is called. Use the IntelliJ IDEA and find the usages.
The jacoco will show you that the particular class is covered but it does not tell you what test has covered the class.